# implement a database application with GUI for Windows, written with Linux

Tags: python, database, user-interface, orm

I have the following data scheme that I want to turn into an application. A regular desktop GUI would probably the best.

[UML Diagram http://img217.imageshack.us/img217/341/56836587.jpg](http://img217.imageshack.us/img217/341/56836587.jpg)
[big version](http://img217.imageshack.us/img217/341/56836587.jpg)

The whole thing would be developed on a Linux (Ubuntu, Gnome) machine, and then used on a Windows Vista computer. If Windows is a problem, I might be able to just run it in a Linux VM later.

My programming language of choice would be Python. I have only used Qt for a two hour project, I have pretty much no experience with GUI. Would Qt work easily on Windows and not look to out of place there? Is GTK a way better option, or is that merely preference issue?

From talking on the #python channel, I gathered that storing the data in a SQLite database would be a good option, and accessing this data via the SQLAlchemy ORM would be better than writing SQL statements by hand. The latter is my usual approach, I want to use this project to learn something better.

Can I just design the dialogues in Qt Designer and use them with my Python objects?

Comment: Did you search for Qt Windows and SQLAlchemy yet?  Please search for the Windows releases of these packages.  After finding the Windows releases, please **update** your question with **specific** topics that concern you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Camelot](http://www.python-camelot.com/)

Comment: Wow, that seems like the all in one solution. It seems like I would not need to do that much GUI after all, but rather translate my data model to Elixier and am done (kind of).

Comment: please note that Camelot recently moved away from Elixir in favor of SQLAlchemy's Declarative model definitions

Answer (score 3):

You might want to check out [Dabo](http://dabodev.com/).

> Dabo is a 3-tier, cross-platform application development framework, written in Python atop the wxPython GUI toolkit

Answer (score 1):

If you are set on using Python them I think Qt would be am excellent choice. It's a fantastic framework that looks good and runs on many platforms. You won't be limited to Windows. Qt can be a bit intimidating but you won't be limited in terms of functionality. The Qt designer works well with Python.

SQLAlchemy works on all common desktop platforms, including Windows.